# How to implement valid restful api for non CRUD feature

Tags: restful-url

I'd like to implement a valid **Restful API**.
I have a resource called "Jobs" and also I implemented CRUD [GET, POST, PUT...] for example: `GET: /api/jobs/1` or `POST: /api/jobs/ with a body {...}`
Now I'd like to add a method to start a job number 1234.
How can i implement this? what should be the URI? What should be the HTTP verb?
Can someone give me an example

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new resource

```
POST /started-jobs?jobId=1234
```

You can edit the state of the job inline:

```
PUT /jobs/1234
{
    "state": "started",
    ..
}
```

You can use a micro-PUT

```
PUT /jobs/1234/state
started
```

That's just off the top of my head. There are surely other options. Which one is best? That requires more information on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Eric, what do you mean by micro-PUT? Is the state resource?what is the started? can you please explain. In addition, in your second option PUT /jobs/1234, I have already use this PUT for updating the object as part of the CRUD. So it's impossible to use it again. Last thing, can I use POST and use /jobs/StartJob { jobId: 1234}

Comment: @user4045308 I mean creating a new endpoint which represents the single property `state`. You can `PUT` the new state as a String to that endpoint.